# Salesforce1 Compact Layout

Tags: mobile, salesforce1-app

Question regarding customizing Salesforce1.  On my contact record detail page, the upper section of the display can be controlled by the Compact Layout.  I get that with no problem.  But I dont know how to control the narrow section right below that.  Its sits just below the top section and above the detail section.  On my contact record, this section contains 2 icons (one is an Email icon, and the other brings up google? maps).  Similarly on the Account record detail page, there are 3 icons, google? maps, google? search, and a 'link' icon that doesnt work.  However, the leads and opportunity record contain no such section.

Answer (score 1):

I believe those are special icons for just the Account and Contact that can't be modified. I also have a phone icon so I can call one of the phone numbers on the record. The link icon should link to the account's web page if you have one filled in on the standard website field.